# Using CSS only to remove the black bars from YouTube HQdefault image?

Tags: html, css

(Did some search but couldn't find the exact same question/answer)

I am displaying the YouTube's hqdefault thumbnails on my page. However, I noticed they are 480 by 360, which means they have black top and bottom bars for all 16:9 ratio videos (which are the majority)

Example is: http://img.youtube.com/vi/dA6Jsr7MWw4/hqdefault.jpg

My question is:

I want the image to auto scale to fit its container's width, which will be a percentage of the total window's width (this means I don't know the exact pixel value in advance). And hide the black bars, and of course don't distort the image's ratio.

Can this be done using CSS only (hopefully with good browser support)? -- I am ok to assume all images should be 16:9 (for those that are of other ratio, I am ok to cut off some part of it, and only display part of it in 16:9).

Thanks

(PS: I have a JS solution, but I want to see if it doable in CSS. The JS solution is to use JS to get the container's width, then set the container's size according to 16:9 ratio. Then stretch the image and position it in the center, hide the extra areas of it -- which basically hides its top and bottom black bars)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/how-to-maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-using-only-css). Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/m0k94ztp/1/) :

You set the div to `width:100%`, it will now stretch to the container size, in this case, the `body`. Then you set the `padding-bottom: 56.25%;` to get the 16:9 ratio.

Now set `overflow: hidden;` to hide what's coming out of the div and set `top: -16.75%;` to hide the upper black strip.

**HTML**

```
<div class="stretchy-wrapper">
    <div>
        <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/dA6Jsr7MWw4/hqdefault.jpg" style="overflow: hidden; width:100%;"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 8px auto;
}

div.stretchy-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    position: relative;
    background: blue;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.stretchy-wrapper > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: -16.75%; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this - set the image as the background to a 16 x 9 div, then just set image width to `100%` and position `50% 50%`

```css
div {
  background:url('http://img.youtube.com/vi/dA6Jsr7MWw4/hqdefault.jpg');
  background-size:100%;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  height:180px;
  width:320px;
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: He asked for a solution that can auto scale to fit its container's width. You're using a fixed size

Comment: There are various ways the OP can achieve that, depending on too many unknowns.

Comment: You are right, and your solution is not one of them. In your solution the image stays the same size when the screen is being scaled.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this jsfiddle will help you. Cheers!

`working url`[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/antonysuthakarj/dz8ndkaq/)

It will be fit even your web application/web site is responsive.